# htaccess redirect for phpBB Forum not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, phpbb

I'm having issues trying to implement a redirect for my phpBB forum. Basically the forum used to be on the root and now it's inside a /foro/ folder.

I already have in place some rules for my Wordpress blog that work perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The thing is that if the user used to go to:

http://www.coliseoweb.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=3567

I want them now to go to:

http://www.coliseoweb.com/foro/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=3567

Keeping all the same variables. I've tried adding this:

```
RewriteRule ^/viewforum.php(.*) /foro/viewforum.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

And also this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/viewtopic.php(.*)$ http://www.coliseoweb.com/foro/viewtopic.php$1
```

But I have no luck.

Maybe they are correct but I'm adding them in the wrong place? Maybe I need something else?

Help would be great!

Thanks!

Javier

Comment: Regex looks correct. Are you putting it before or after the default Wordpress regex, because WP may pick it up beforehand

Comment: I tried both cases, basically I tried after: "RewriteBase /", where should I put it?

Comment: I have uploaded this htacces:

    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteRule ^/viewtopic.php(.*) /foro/viewtopic.php$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/viewforum.php(.*) /foro/viewforum.php$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/ucp.php(.*) /foro/ucp.php$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/memberlist.php(.*) /foro/memberlist.php$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/faq.php(.*) /foro/faq.php$1 [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Go here:

http://www.coliseoweb.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=3567

It doesn't redirect :S

Comment: That's right, I think it should go just after `RewriteBase /`. First, just be aware you've used both `/viewforum.php` and `viewtopic.php` as examples, so it could get confusing when testing. Anyway, to test redirects, I sometimes just try linking to google.com or whatever to make sure my regex is working. Try: `RewriteRule ^/viewforum.php(.*) http://www.google.com [R=301,L]` and see what happens

Comment: I tried after RewriteBase / and nothing :S

Comment: See my answer; your regex doesn't need the leading slash. My answer works for me locally.

Answer (score 1):

Ah sorry! Your regex doesn't need the leading slash. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^viewforum.php(.*) /foro/viewforum.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should better replace the code `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` on your code with `RewriteRule ^viewforum.php([^/]*) /foro/viewforum.php$1 [R=301,L]`

Now, if you need to have both working... Then you could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^viewforum.php([^/]*) /foro/viewforum.php$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: But wouldn't that break the Wordpress htaccess settings? I need to have both working...